# $f\cos(\phi) + g\sin(\phi)=1$ and $f\sin(\phi)-g\cos(\phi)=0 \implies f = \cos\phi$ and $g = \sin(\phi)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Let $f, g$ be smooth functions such that $f\cos(\phi) + g\sin(\phi)=1$ and $f\sin(\phi)-g\cos(\phi)=0$.  Prove $f = \cos\phi$ and $g = \sin(\phi)$.  It seems easy but I'm not sure where to begin

Comment: Notice that this is almost always a system of 2 independent linear equations.

Comment: Ah very clever thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $f(x) \sin x \cos x = \sin x - g(x) \sin^2 x = g(x) \cos^2(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R},$ so that $g(x) = \sin x.$ We deduce that $f(x) \sin(x) = \sin(x) \cos(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R},$ so $f(x) = \cos x$ whenever $x \neq k \pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Since $f$ is smooth, it must be the case that $g(x) = \cos(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R},$ which finishes the proof.